# Realm writes data every time the app loads

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm, realm-migration

I'm writing an App, that takes information from an Excel document and saves the Data in Realm. My problem is, that every time I open the App, the Realm Database will save a copy of the Information. Now I get my TableViews with 3 times the same items.

Here is the code in my Main View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    var importExcel = Import()

    
    var xslxConvert = xslxConverter()
    
    var currentString: [String] = []
    
    var Name = ""
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var VRLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var configurationLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        currentString = importExcel.Results()
        
        Label.text = Name
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.saveData()
            print("Data from Excel saved")
        }
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - SaveData to the Realm
    
    func saveData() {
        
        do {
            try realm.write {
                for item in currentString {
                    let newItem = FunctionData()
                    newItem.functionName = item
                    realm.add(newItem)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print ("Error trying to Realm data, \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

How can I make a filter of something, to make that the App just save the Information from Excel ones?
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Your `viewDidLoad` function is calling `self.saveData()` which means every time the app is opened. `saveData()` is called. So, that's doing exactly what you're telling it to do. Are you expecting a different behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think it doesn't work with UUID(), because it will be different all time.

```
let filter = // choose what you need
if let items = Array(realm.objects(FunctionData.self).filter("parameterName == %@", filter)) {
     // Do not save
} else {
     // Save
}
```

And try to use `realm.add(newItem, update: .modified)` for saving

Comment: Hello! Thank your for your answer. My Model has " functionID = UUID().uuidString" as a primary key. From there we have of course many items and many UUIDs. I've asked me also how can we do what you say, but for all UUIDs

Comment: Little bit changed my answer. Check pls this way